# TypeError: forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x' when my code does not have forward() nor x

Tags: python, pytorch

I am currently facing the problem of error

```
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)  File "c:\Users\user\Fuzzy-Integral-Covid-Detection-main\appTestBackup.py", line 333, in get_probability
    model=model().eval()

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
TypeError: forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

The code of the problem of the source is, which I am confused as there is no forward() nor x, so what is actually the problem? The model has been updated and the location of model is in the function learningPart()

The location where the error have is at the model = model.eval()

```
    def get_probability(self,image_datasets,model,data_dir,model_name):
        data_dir="./data/"
        num_epochs=100
        logger.log(logging.INFO, 'Getting the Probability Distribution')
        # print("\nGetting the Probability Distribution")
        testloader=torch.utils.data.DataLoader(image_datasets['val'],batch_size=1)

        model=model.eval()

        correct = 0
        total = 0
        import csv
        import numpy as np
        f = open(data_dir+'/'+model_name+".csv",'w+',newline = '')
        writer = csv.writer(f)

        with torch.no_grad():
            num = 0
            temp_array = np.zeros((len(testloader),num_classes))
            for data in testloader:
                images, labels = data
                labels=labels.cuda()
                outputs = model(images.cuda())
                _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)
                total += labels.size(0)
                correct += (predicted == labels.cuda()).sum().item()
                prob = torch.nn.functional.softmax(outputs, dim=1)
                temp_array[num] = np.asarray(prob[0].tolist()[0:num_classes])
                num+=1
        logger.log(logging.INFO, "Accuracy = ",100*correct/total)
        # print("Accuracy = ",100*correct/total)
```

This is the location where the model training takes place

```
def learningPart(self, data_dir,num_epochs):
        mean = np.array([0.485, 0.456, 0.406])
        std = np.array([0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
        
        # data_dir="./data/"

        data_transforms = {
            'train': transforms.Compose([
                transforms.Resize((224,224)),
                transforms.ToTensor(),
                transforms.Normalize(mean, std)
            ]),
            'val': transforms.Compose([
                transforms.Resize((224,224)),
                transforms.ToTensor(),
                transforms.Normalize(mean, std)
            ]),
        }

        image_datasets = {x: datasets.ImageFolder(os.path.join(data_dir, x),
                                            data_transforms[x])
                    for x in ['train', 'val']}
        
        global dataloaders
        dataloaders = {x: torch.utils.data.DataLoader(image_datasets[x], batch_size=1,
                                                    shuffle=True, num_workers=1)
                    for x in ['train', 'val']}
        
        global dataset_sizes
        dataset_sizes = {x: len(image_datasets[x]) for x in ['train', 'val']}
        
        global class_names
        class_names = image_datasets['train'].classes
        
        global num_classes
        num_classes = len(class_names)
        
        global device
        device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
        # print(class_names)
        logger.log(logging.INFO, class_names)

        #Get probability distributions from the 4 models
        # global num_epochs
        num_epochs = 100

        global criterion
        criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
        
        # Get a batch of training data
        global inputs, classes
        inputs, classes = next(iter(dataloaders['train']))

        model = models.vgg11_bn(pretrained = True)
        optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.0001, momentum = 0.99)
        step_lr_scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size = 10, gamma=0.1)
        num_ftrs = model.classifier[0].in_features
        model.classifier = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, num_classes)
        model = model.to(device)
        model = Thread(target=self.train_model(model, criterion, optimizer, step_lr_scheduler, num_epochs=num_epochs, model_name = 'Kaggle_vgg11')).start()
        self.get_probability(image_datasets,model,data_dir,model_name='Kaggle_vgg11')
```

Comment: As you can see if you read the whole error message, `forward()` and `x` is used in "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", a.k.a PyTorch module you are using.

Comment: At which line does this error arise? You are using some pytorch function improperly which is giving the error.

Comment: @matszwecja module.py is the library, but I have no idea on how I called the library

Comment: Then you might want to ask yourself why you have no idea what is going on in your code. You cannot call a library by accident.

Comment: @Ach113 my guess is from model=model.eval()

Comment: @RyanLIM No need to guess. The error report tells you exactly where the problem originates

Comment: @AlbertWinestein any ideas that might cause this issue?

Comment: `model` is almost certainly a class that extends `torch.nn.Module`. When you use `model(images.cuda())` you are effectively calling `model.forward(images.cuda())` (with some pytorch-internal stuff in between). Based on your error the best guess is that your model's `forward` method is implemented incorrectly or it is expecting more than one argument. You will need to post additional information about how `model` was defined, preferably it's implementation.

Comment: @AlbertWinestein thanks for mentioning, I have updated the model part, it is at learningPart()

Comment: @jodag thanks for mentioning about the part that is lacked, I have updated the model part, which is at learningPart()

Comment: `models.vgg11_bn` doesn't actually tell us much. It seems you have a local package named `models` (probably `models.py`) that defines a function `vgg11_bn` that actually builds your model.

Comment: @jodag models is actually imported from the torchvision library, which is from torchvision import models

Comment: Ah I see. the problem is actually that you are using `model().eval()` somewhere in your code. The code you posted doesn't actually have this line. It should be `model.eval()` like in the code you posted. If you're using Jupyter notebook then make sure to rerun the cells that define your functions.

Comment: Actually I am doing in VS code, the problem is actually I don't have model().eval(), the only place with model.eval() is at the function get_probability()

Comment: @jodag the full code can be accessed here paste.ofcode.org/tkmNyHNHfQsH7V5q6VCZzX

Comment: `c:\Users\user\Fuzzy-Integral-Covid-Detection-main\appTestBackup.py` appears to certainly have `model().eval()`. Are you sure you're not accidentally running backup code that is broken. Looks like it based on error messages.

Comment: Nope, absolutely not. Actually this is why I am confused about it too

Comment: You have `model = Thread(...).start()` in your code. `model` becomes `None` after this call.